# Master/Child with alternative linking fields in the child table

Tags: delphi

There is probably a simple solution to this but I'm stumped.

I have a master table with one ID field.  There is a child table with that ID in two possible fields.  Think of a doubles team with Player A and Player B.  The Master table will have two records, one for each player.  The Child will have one record with the Player A ID in one field and the Player B ID in a second field.

When I use the Master/Child and I'm sitting on Player A I will only see the child records if Player A is in the first ID field.  If I move to Player B then I see nothing in the child table if Player B ID is in the second field.

Any help?

Thanks,

Don

Answer (score 3):

> The Child will have one record with the Player A ID in one field and the Player B ID in a second field.

In that case, you should consider using an fkInternalCalc field on the Detail table (if your TDataSet type supports fkInternalCalc fields, and deriving its value in the `Detail's` OnCalcFields event however suits your data model) and use that as the Detail field in an Index on the Detail table for selecting records which match the master.  But generally speaking, needing to do that (i.e, link the Detail records on values from different fields) is a sign of imperfect data-modelling** - you might do better to have an intermediate "linking" table between the two tables you currently have,e.g. linking the Detail records to the Master on the basis of PlayerID, regardless of whether the player is "PlayerA" or "PlayerB".

** - the reason being that, as you have obviously gathered, the Master could be linked to the Detail on the basis of two different fields in the Detail table, and that does not fit with how M-D relationships traditionally work in Delphi (i.e. a single field or combination of fields with no alternatives) and in fact an extra, "linking" table is the better way to model the situation where the link needs to be defined on the basis of the values in Detail fields IDFieldA and IDFieldB.

Btw, what TDataSet descendant types are you using?

Comment: I believe I am doing what you have in your first suggestion.  Master table with an index on the playerID.  The problem seems to be I want the child to show up whether the PlayerID from the master table is in the child ID field 1 or field 2.

Comment: " I want the child to show up whether the PlayerID "  If you have the tables correctly linked, by whichever method, you shouldn't need to do that.  Btw, see updates to answer.

Comment: I should have added the components you asked for.  It's very simple; a couple of tdbgrids, tdatasource and tTables.

Comment: I agree with your model assessment, but there may have been a good reason for it (i.e. the glass is half full). In my answer, the query result looks the way we would have liked it to have been designed, and should work the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Gday,

If I read you aright, you want to return each child row that has the parent ID in either A or B.

To do this in a query, you could write:

`select A, field1, field2...
from
    childtable
where
    A = :keyvalue
union all
select B, field1, field2...
from
    childtable
where
    B = :keyvalue`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Actually, I prefer your answer to mine, so +1, but of course it depends on the OP's datasets supporting SQL, which he hasn't said yet.

Comment: I would like to thank you all for the suggestions.  I was finally able to write a "onfilterrecord" correctly to test the two fields and it does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler and much faster running answer to the UNION ALL join is

```
SELECT Mast.* ,DetA.* ,DetB.* FROM 
MAST
JOIN Det AS DetA ON Mast.AID=DetA.Det_ID
JOIN Det AS DetB ON Mast.BID=DetB.Det_ID
```

If you want to be able to have any number of players in the game, then each Det record (player) needs to point to the master using the Mast_ID. You can do a similar join that way, but you will get one record per player if you do. The way I did it above gives you one record for each master/detail A/Detail B combination.